# What Unix command can I use to enforce a limit of 100 files in a folder?

Tags: unix, filesystems

I would like to delete the oldest files in a directory, after a limit of 100 files. In other words, I want to ensure that no more than 100 files exist in the directory, and if a limit is exceeded, delete the oldest files after the limit. I don't just want to delete files older than x days, since if this was run on a cronjob, eventually all files would be deleted.

I guess if I were to program this, the pseudo code would be:

```
list = dir.getFiles()
list.sortByDate()
deleteList = list.getSubList(100, end) // from, to
deleteAll(deleteList)
```

So what would the appropriate Unix command be? I guess `find` would be involved somehow with the `-exec` argument, but I'm not sure about the sorting/limiting aspect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find` should not be necessary. If you first go to the right dir,

```
rm -f `ls -rt | head -n -100`
```

to specify a path

```
rm -f `ls -rt /path/to/my/dir | head -n -100`
```

and for `cron` (on Ubuntu!)

```
/bin/rm -f `/bin/ls -rt /path/to/my/dir | /usr/bin/head -n -100`
```

A command path can be determined using `which`, e.g.

```
which ls
```

Finally, if file names contain spaces, they should be quoted `ls -Q` then sent to `xargs`

```
/bin/ls -Qrt /path/to/my/dir | /usr/bin/head -n -100 | /usr/bin/xargs /bin/rm -f
```

(tested on Ubuntu, for your tests, replace `rm -f` with `echo` to see what is to be deleted)

Comment: Small typo: use `head -n 100` instead of `head -n -100`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm running this from a cronjob. How do I get full paths?

Comment: This is not a typo, the `ls` is `-rt` so we need `-100` to tell `head` to get rid of the 100 newest lines/files! To set full paths, simply put it in the `ls`, for instance `ls -rt /my/path/to/dir | head -n -100`. For `cron`, `ls` ... should better have their full path. Please see my edit above.

Comment: Use `xargs` instead, or files may not be handled as you expect (for example, spaces): `ls -rt | head -n -100 | xargs rm -f`

Comment: If you have spaces in file names, `xargs` needs also the `Q` option of `ls`. Edited again.

Comment: Good catch, and +1 for completeness.

Comment: `ls` is not *giving* me the full paths, which is required, since I need to run the command from `cron`. It seems to me that `find` is the only command that will *give* me full paths.

Comment: I guess I'll just use `cd` in my script since printing full paths isn't possible.

Comment: @nbolton Yes, that was at the top of my answer: cd to the relevant dir first.

Answer (score 0):

Are you reinventing the wheel called log rotation? If so, use logrotate (on linux systems; other systems will have their own equivalent programs).

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd use logrotate to do this. Baring in mind that I don't want to rename the files or delete them after each file name has been rotated x number of times. Please give an example of how logrotate could do the same thing as ring0's example.